# How to fix login page Laravel ui auth didn't display any error message when wrong input email/password

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I have project build in Laravel 8 and have login page on it, but I have problem, the login page didnt show any error message when user input wrong password or email.
here is my login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
           
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']))) {
            if (auth()->user()) {
                return redirect()->route('home.index');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('error', 'Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my login view

```
@extends('layouts.pre')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class=" row justify-content-center">
        <div class=" col-md-6">
            <div class=" card ">


                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5%" class="text-center">Login</h3><br>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('') }}</label>

                            

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                            {{ __('Remember Me ') }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container ">
                                <div class="form-group row mb-0 float-sm-right mr-5">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn blue">
                                            <a class="text-white">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I want to show eror message like "Username or Password are Wrong, Please try again". How to do it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Session` to get errors in blade template:

```
@if(Session::has('error'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ Session::get('error')}}
</div>
@endif
```